# How can I make the unix `pass` program play nice with `ssh` inside the Linux Virtual Terminal?

Tags: bash, ssh, password-store

I am trying to log into an ssh server by pulling the password directly out of the `pass` program without any GUI interaction.

The normal workflow in the GUI (Gnome) is to do the following.

1. Pull the password into the clipboard: `pass -c Misc/MyAccount`
2. Do the ssh program and paste using the GUI clipboard

   ```
   ssh myserver
   Right-Click + Paste
   ```

Since I wanted to do this without the GUI component, I figured that I could do something like this

```
 pass Misc/MyAccount | ssh myserver
```

Obviously, this does not work because `ssh` does not precisley read the password from `stdin`. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340366/how-to-make-ssh-receive-the-password-from-stdin) and created the following script instead.

```
export SSH_ASKPASS="/path/to/script/calling/pass"
setsid ssh "myserver"
```

This works great when I am running it inside `gnome-terminal` inside the GUI.

However, it fails in the Linux Virtual Terminal (from Control-Alt-F1) because the password prompt for `pass` cannot pop up as it normally does (directly in the terminal), so the login simply fails.

How can I make this work in the Linux virtual terminal?

#### Desired Behavior

1. Run the above script.
2. See the prompt for the password for the `pass` program.
3. Successfully login without manually typing in the password to the `ssh` server.

Answer (score 0):

There are some requirements to get it to work:

- You need to set something (anything will do) in `DISPLAY` environment variable to activate `SSH_ASKPASS` feature.
- You need `gpg-agent` and tty-based [pinentry](https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/pinentry/) program.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems run `apt-get install pinentry-curses` and use `/usr/bin/pinentry-curses`.

Run the script as follows:

```
export DISPLAY=anything
export SSH_ASKPASS="/path/to/script/calling/pass"
gpg-agent --pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses --daemon setsid ssh myserver
```

Note that `setsid` of util-linux in recent distributions (Debian 8.0 or later, Ubuntu 14.10 or later) need `-w` to wait for the subprocess termination, otherwise you will get confused with a ssh session running in the background.

```
gpg-agent --pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses --daemon setsid -w ssh myserver
```